# Showing that a solution actually solves the Dirichlet-Poisson PDE problem

Tags: probability-theory, partial-differential-equations, stochastic-processes, boundary-value-problem

I'm looking at the "Dirichlet-Poisson problem" section of [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_processes_and_boundary_value_problems) Wikipedia page. It writes that, under proper assumptions,

$$u(x) = \mathbb{E}[g(X_{T_{D}})] + \mathbb{E}\left[\int_{0}^{T_{D}}f(X_{t})dt\right]$$

provides a solution to

$$-Lu(x) = f(x), x \in D$$
$$\lim_{y \rightarrow x} u(y) = g(x), x \in \partial D,$$

for variables as defined in the problem. I'm just wondering if someone could show me the steps that confirm that, under the assumptions given in the article, this solution holds. Thanks!

Comment: what is the process $X_t$?

Comment: @almosteverywhere It's a Markov Chain indexed by time. The particular $X_{T}$ is the value of X at the time of stopping.